# modx phpthumbof returns strange image

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, phpthumb

I try to use the phpthumbof modx addon in an getResources template chunk as a snippet, like shown in the code below. But it always gives me back this strange image with its version and the text "error messages disables" in red color and on a violet background.

Here my snippet call:

```
<img src="[[!phpthumbof? &input=`[[+tv.content__gallery__image]]` &options=`w=100&h100`]]" />
```

Comment: no any modx and/or apache logs?

Comment: nope, nothing that gives me a hint. sorry that I can't provide more information.

Comment: Check the output of `[[+tv.content__gallery__image]]` is correct, without the snippet?

Comment: it is, the img tag i showed above is nested in an anchore with the url to the image for use with photoswipe - and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your snippet call with the height property, try this:

```
<img src="[[!phpthumbof? &input=`[[+tv.content__gallery__image]]` &options=`w=100&h=100`]]" />
```

Next check that imageMagick is working properly on your server. That error sounds like a missing ImageMagick install.

P.S I would also recommend you to take a look at the pThump extra to replace phpthumbof. It does the same thing, but is a lot faster.